# How to re-import a variable during runtime in python?

Tags: python, class, variables, python-import

There is a module `module_1`, it has:

```
A = 5
B = 6

def change_A():
    global A
    A = 10
```

another module `module_2`, it has:

```
from module_1 import *

class x():
    def __init__():
        self.y = A
```

So, I run `module_2` and create `x` object, the attribute `y` is 5. Then I want to change `x.y` to 10, I call `change_A()` function in `module_1`. But `x.y` doesn't change to 10 (because I imported `A` in the beginning).

```
m = x()

change_A()

print m.y

>>> 5
```

Could you please tell me how to change `A` in runtime?

Comment: Forget about the modules. `a = 1; x.b = a; a += 1` does not change `x.b` under any circumstances because `int`s are immutable.

Comment: Don't you know `self.y` and `A` are two different variables? You have changed A (check it by `print(module1.A)`).

Comment: you can try reload(module_1)